# How to multiply pair-wise tuple list

Tags: python

I know how to multiply the elements of a single tuple:

```
tup = (2,3)
tup[0]*tup[1]
6
```

My question is how do you multiply the elements of several tuples using a for loop?

example: How do I get `x = (4,5,6)` when `x = ((2,2), (5,1), (3,2))`?

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
tuple(a*b for a, b in x)
```

Answer (score 2):

for tuples of any length, one line script:

```
>>> tpl = ((2,2), (5,1), (3,2,4))
>>> tuple(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, tp) for tp in tpl)
(4, 5, 24)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ((2, 2), (5, 1), (3, 2))
y = ((2, 3), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 5, 7))

def multiply_the_elements_of_several_tuples_using_a_for_loop(X):
    tuple_of_products = []

    for x in X:
        product = 1

        for element in x:
            product *= element

        tuple_of_products.append(product)

    return tuple(tuple_of_products)

print(multiply_the_elements_of_several_tuples_using_a_for_loop(x))
print(multiply_the_elements_of_several_tuples_using_a_for_loop(y))
```

Output:

```
(4, 5, 6)
(6, 30, 210)
```

Comment: Plus for handling any length inner tuple

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it on tuples of any length:

```
tuple(product(myTuple) for myTuple in ((2,2), (5,1), (3,2)))
```

where

```
def product(cont):
  base = 1
  for e in cont:
    base *= e
  return base
```